# Check if user's email exists in db

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, authentication

I have a basic login form and want to authenticate whether a user's email exists in the db, but am not sure of the syntax for angular + node.

Main.js I have a ng-click on the submit button which runs this function. I get the email from the input and somehow need to pass this on to check the db?

```
$scope.logIn = function() {
    var email = $scope.formInfo.email;

    $http.get('/findUser').success(function(response){
        console.log('find user data');
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Server.js I have the connection to the db but am unsure of how to make the connection with the client and backend data or what the syntax is

```
app.get('/findUser', function(req, res){
//what do I do here?
    db.rejoin_your_ex.find({ email: 'the user's email' }, function(err, docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side**

```
$scope.logIn = function() {
   var email = $scope.formInfo.email;

   $http({
       url: '/findUser', 
       method: "GET",
       params: {"email": email}
   }).success(function(response){
       console.log('find user data');
       console.log(response);
   });
};
```

**Server Side**

At backend, you can use [Mongoskin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoskin) module for mongodb specific queries.

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
db.bind('user');

app.get('/findUser', function(req, res){
    //what do I do here?
    db.user.find({ email: req.params.email }, function(err, user){
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps you.